# How to increase column size of netezza table

Tags: netezza, clob, varchar2, custom-data-type

i have to insert a very long string ~ 65KB into two column in the table each. But in netezza, table size is limited to ~ 65KB. Is there any way like CLOB or dynamic datatype or anything that can store such long string in NZ table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

You'll need to do a horizontal partition and put each large string column in its own table with a common integer primary key.